# Run JavaScript code on a page without showing browser window

Tags: javascript, browser, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a question regarding JavaScript and methods by which its code can be run. As we know, there is some JavaScript code embedded in  tags and it runs natively within browser window - that's quite common and that's how the web pages currently work.

If we want interaction out of the box with the web page we are surfing, we must use tool such as GreaseMonkey and write our UserScripts that allow us to change page behavior to our desired one. This still needs us to open browser window and visit our target.

The question is: can we somehow run JavaScript code on a certain page without even opening browser window? I mean, in an ideal solution there would be a command-line tool that'd allow us to call:

```
./clibrowser http://google.com userscript.js
```

In which script, for example, we could run some AJAX code to fetch data coming from queries and pass it to some other PHP script that's save it to database.

I think that this question simplifies to: **are there any tools like "command-line browser" with JavaScript engine?** I know, that it may sound strange, but I am curious just because of the idea I have in my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is. There is NodeJS, which runs on Chrome's V8 javascript engine: http://nodejs.org/.

There is also Rhino, which runs on Java: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/.

The thing about these is that they don't include a "browser" as such... they are just javascript engines that can execute javascript, but don't provide the ability to parse/manipulate HTML, *out of the box*. However, there are javascript libraries built upon these engines that do simplify most of the work for you.

Comment: Can Node.JS load a page and interact with its code? Can you point me to the resources on that topic?

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk - I think you're asking for HTML scraping? Yes, NodeJS does that very well. Using `request` to pull web pages, and `jsdom` and a port of `jQuery`, you can simply use jQuery to find text/elements on any page. Take a look at this: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/jsdom-jquery-in-5-lines-on-nodejs

Comment: I knew that Node exists, but I wasn't aware of the fact, that it can be used that way. My last question would be - can Node scripts be run directly from command line? Every resource I've read shows Node's source code, but there is no "command line" execution examples.

Comment: @Tomasz Kowalczyk - Also look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393757/scripting-with-server-side-javascript/4394945#4394945

Comment: @Tomasz, to run from command line you simply do: `node myApp.js`

Answer (score 0):

There is phantomjs: http://phantomjs.org which is a webkit-based headless browser with full support for javascript. It exposes an interface that lets you navigate to a page, interact with it and run whatever scripts you want in that page's context.